# How to use several requirements.txt profiles with Django App at Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, setup.py, requirements.txt

I've been trying to deploy a Django web app at Heroku and I'm using this layout for requirements:

```
requirements/
├── base.txt
├── local.txt
├── production.txt
├── staging.txt
└── test.txt
requirements.txt
```

**requirements.txt**

```
# This file is expected by Heroku.

-r requirements/staging.txt  # I have to change this for each env
```

I thought that depending on an environment variable Heroku would pick the apropiate txt file. The thing is that after multiple attempts and searching the docs I realized that Heroku only picks requirements.txt and no other file. So I can only push to heroku for staging and if I need to push for another environment, I have to change requirements.txt in the repo or having an alternative branch only for this file.

I'm thinking of using Heroku for at least a couple of environments, so I'd like to be able to manage more than one Heroku environment. So I went to investigate and I learnt that is possible to make a setup.py excluding the requirements.txt and managing this, but while reading the docs I couldn't understand yet how can I make setup.py pick the good requirements file among the multiple ones I have.

I suppose somebody must have wanted to do this, although I saw that setup.py docs discourages this way of procedure.

I guess another way to do this would be to give away everything about requirements files (though I like them) and do it all through setup.py, which I'm not familiarized with, so I'm asking here the solutions I can use for installing my dependencies at Heroku and other environments while maintaining the different dependencies separated in each environment file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you have different dependencies for different environments but the _same_ version of the code? Testing in a lower environment is only useful if you're confident you'll get the same behaviour in a higher one, which is hard when the dependencies could be entirely different.

Comment: For example, I could think that in the 'test' environment I could add the django debug toolbar but not in the staging one. 

Also, for a new version with new functionality, I could need new dependencies added in staging.txt, but not in production.txt, where I shouldn't need to change anything if I had to do some quick fix from another branch, for instance.

Comment: For the first example you'd be better conditionally _activating_ it, based on e.g. env vars, rather than conditionally _installing_ it. The second example makes no sense - that would be a different version of the code entirely, if it's not ready for prod it simply _won't be deployed there yet_.

Comment: So explain me your proposal in your answer and I would would be delighted to study it and apply it to my project if I check it to do whatever I want

Comment: The proposal is: don't. That's too short for an answer, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The second example assumes having a staging environment at Heroku, as well as a production one,also at Heroku.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but that environment would be running _different code_, a different commit entirely, in which the normal `requirements.txt` would have whatever _that version of code_ requires.

Comment: So I would just manage this by having different branches, one for staging and one for production?

Comment: use piplock file and mention the environment there

Comment: Not necessarily. Ideally promoting to production would be taking a known-good commit and deploying _exactly the same code_ that ran in staging, which doesn't need any branching at all - production would just be running (generally) an older commit on the same branch. You _could_ use different branches, if you really need to manage multiple versions concurrently, but that adds substantial complexity and room for mistakes. None of this requires (or benefits from) the same commit having multiple requirements files for different environments it might run in.

Comment: In general questions where the full answer is a whole book aren't a good fit for SO; in this case, it's https://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html.